# KnockoutJS binding select

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new in KO, and I am missing something important:(

Please tell me why these code doesnt work ? Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8p4B/
I am so frustrated. Why selectedItem doesnt set value in "select".

Html:

```
    <select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedItem"></select>
```

ViewModel:

```
    var viewModel = {
    /*selectedItem: ko.observable(3), I also try but without success */
    selectedItem: 3,
    items: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.items([
        {id: 1, name:"pencil"},
        {id: 2, name:"pen"},
        {id: 3, name:"marker"},
        {id: 4, name:"crayon"}
    ]);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Take care when including resources to be used in your fiddles. "Github is not a CDN" and JSFiddle has been adhering to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `selectedItem` **after** you have populated your `items` array:

```
var viewModel = {
    selectedItem: ko.observable(),
    items: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.items([
        {id: 1, name:"pencil"},
        {id: 2, name:"pen"},
        {id: 3, name:"marker"},
        {id: 4, name:"crayon"},
    ]);
    viewModel.selectedItem(3);
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nfqR/).

In your original code KO is setting the `selectedItem` to `undefined` when you are calling the `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` because the `items` collection is empty when the binding is applied. So by the time you populate your `viewModel.items` your original `selectedItem` is lost (see also in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AU98S/)).